# Find and replace a specific part of a string with a backslash in a field

Tags: mysql, serialization

For example this is `myTable`:

```
| i | data    |
+---+---------+
| 1 | d\one   |
| 2 | d\two   |
| 3 | d\three |
```

But I want to change it to:

```
| i | data  |
+---+-------+
| 1 | one   |
| 2 | two   |
| 3 | three |
```

I know how to find a specific part of a string with a backslash in a field:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE data LIKE 'd%\%'
```

I know how to find & replace a field a value, only this query won't work:

```
UPDATE myTable SET data=REPLACE(data,'d\','') WHERE data LIKE 'd%\%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you should put triple slash `\\\` instead of double slash `\\` in `Like Clause`. As I have tried I am unable to pick data from using `\\`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data LIKE 'd\\%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data LIKE 'd\\\%';
+---------+
| data    |
+---------+
| d\one   |
| d\two   |
| d\three |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT REPLACE(data,'d\\','') FROM mytable WHERE data LIKE 'd\\\%';
+------------------------+
| REPLACE(data,'d\\','') |
+------------------------+
| one                    |
| two                    |
| three                  |
+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE mytable SET data =  REPLACE(data,'d\\','') WHERE data LIKE 'd\\\%';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+-------+
| data  |
+-------+
| one   |
| two   |
| three |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for the anwsers, but I found out the answer to this question by myself with a source no one is referring to. You have to understand what the \ does in MySQL, it's a **[special character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences)**.
Anyway, I used it for this `http:/\/\..` so It wasn't necessary to use the tripple backslash in the LIKE state where you're is talking about. In this case I also could use `http%/%/..` for that string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET data = REPLACE(data,'d\\','') 
WHERE data INSTR('d\\') = 1
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff95be/2)

Comment: You shouldn't use `instr` as you suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21904107/792290

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
UPDATE myTable SET `data`=REPLACE(`data`,'d\','');
```