# MySQL Escape Character Issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

While I was trying to solve  [**This Question.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903509/find-and-replace-a-specific-part-of-a-string-with-a-backslash-in-a-field)  I created the dummy records in a table

```
create table mytable(data CHAR(30));

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('d\\one'),('d\\two'),('d\\three');

SELECT * FROM mytable;
+---------+
| data    |
+---------+
| d\one   |
| d\two   |
| d\three |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now when i am selecting records, I am getting no result, I have tried many combination with like but no luck.

**Ex :**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data LIKE "d\\%";
Empty set (0.00 sec)


SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data LIKE 'd\\%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use triple slash:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data LIKE "d\\\%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) instead

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE instr(data, 'd\\') = 1
```

Comment: I wonder if MySQL will use index for that (because for `LIKE 'substring%'` it will). But - need to test..